# Find $T^{-1}$ of $T: \mathcal{P}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2 $ with $T(p(x)) = p(x+2)$ and basis of codomain $\{1, x+2, (x+2)^2\}$

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations, inverse-function

> Let $T$ be a linear transformation. Find $T^{-1}$ of $T: \mathcal{P}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_2 $ with $T(p(x)) = p(x+2)$ with basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$ and $\{1, x+2, (x+2)^2\}$ respectively.

I am aware the matrix of this linear transformation is the identity matrix, thus I know $T$ is invertible.

I am unsure how to find $T^{-1}$ with respect to the basis $\{1, x+2, (x+2)^2\}$.

$T^{-1}(a + b(x+2) + c(x+2)^2)$ should map to $a + bx + cx^2$

Comment: In this basis $T$ is just identity, so...

Comment: What do you mean by finding $T^{-1}$ with certain bases? Do you meant finding the *matrix* of $T^{-1}$ with respect to those bases?